# Flutter error: No TabController for TabBarView

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, tabs

I want to add some tabs in my flutter page, but without having a page just with tabs.

For short, I have some input fields, and underneath them I want to put my Tabs.

I keep getting this error: No TabController for TabBarView. I already gave the state class to be with TickerProviderStateMixin for the controller to work, but I can't figure out why it says that no tabcontroller is found, when it exists.

The problem is that I already have a tab controller, this is the code:

```
class ProductBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductBodyState createState() => _ProductBodyState();
}
class _ProductBodyState extends State<ProductBody> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
   
    _controller = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                "Select category:",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
         
            Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              child: new TabBar(
                controller: _controller,
                tabs: [
                   Tab(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
                    text: 'Address',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.my_location),
                    text: 'Location',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
             Container(
              height: 80.0,
              child: new TabBarView(
                controller: _controller,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Card(
                    child: new ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
                      title: new TextField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search for address...'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Card(
                    child: new ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.location_on),
                      title: new Text('Latitude: 48.09342\nLongitude: 11.23403'),
                      trailing: new IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.my_location), onPressed: () {}),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`. You have just one controller.

And there is no any problem I passed your code dartpad it worked properly. Check your other codes.
[image]

Just open https://dartpad.dartlang.org/flutter and paste these codes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ProductBody(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductBodyState createState() => _ProductBodyState();
}
class _ProductBodyState extends State<ProductBody> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
   
    _controller = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                "Select category:",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
         
            Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              child: new TabBar(
                controller: _controller,
                tabs: [
                   Tab(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
                    text: 'Address',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.my_location),
                    text: 'Location',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
             Container(
              height: 80.0,
              child: new TabBarView(
                controller: _controller,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Card(
                    child: new ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
                      title: new TextField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search for address...'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Card(
                    child: new ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.location_on),
                      title: new Text('Latitude: 48.09342\nLongitude: 11.23403'),
                      trailing: new IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.my_location), onPressed: () {}),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code with `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` , same error: `No TabController for TabBar.`

Comment: The problem is not there. I passed your code in dartpad it worked properly.

Comment: Can you give me the link for the dartpad?

Comment: Unfortunatly We can't share codes with dartpad. Just open https://dartpad.dartlang.org/flutter and past your code. Replace the ProductBody widget with MyWidget.

Comment: It's not working, it has a lot of errors: `Type 'StatefulWidget' not found.` `Type 'BuildContext' not found.`

Comment: I don't understand why, but I restarted my app, and now it work with no problem. It works with both `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` and `TickerProviderStateMixin` .

Answer (score 1):

You can use bottom Navigation tabs. The tab bar will appear in the bottom of the page, and works just like a default tab bar

https://medium.com/@uncoded_decimal/creating-bottom-navigation-tabs-using-flutter-2286681450d4